# mongo mapReduce to group by object id create date gives too little results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mapreduce

i'm using this to get the count by day for users created, but when i sum up all the counts of the results i'm getting an overall of about 10K users when my collection has 200K. 
what am i missing?

```
var mapFn= function() { 
    var dt = this._id.getTimestamp();
    var yr = dt.getFullYear();
    var mo = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var dy = dt.getDate();
    var dt_str = yr + '-' + ((mo<10)?'0'+mo:mo) + '-' + ((dy<10)?'0'+dy:dy);
    emit( dt_str, 1);
};
var redFn = function(k, v) {
    return v.length;

};

db.users.mapReduce(mapFn, redFn, {out:{ "inline": 1 }});
```

Comment: I think that the return in your reduce function should match the structure of emit. Also, you can do users count by day using aggregation as well. Look here if you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293082/mongodb-group-by-hour/23295031#23295031

Comment: thank you Lalit, however the aggregation requires a date field. i have only the _id field and no "created_at" field. i did not understand what you mean by "should match the structure of emit". the emit emits an number (1) and v.length is also a number. should i do something else to "match" them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently the v in the reduce function is an array of arrays. very bad documentation on mongos part. still really happy it works :)

this is the code:

```
var mapFn= function() { 
    var dt = this._id.getTimestamp();
    var yr = dt.getFullYear();
    var mo = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var dy = dt.getDate();
    var dt_str = yr + '-' + ((mo<10)?'0'+mo:mo) + '-' + ((dy<10)?'0'+dy:dy);
    emit( dt_str, {count: 1});
};
var redFn = function(k, v) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) { total += v[i].count; }
    return {count: total};    
};

db.users.mapReduce(mapFn, redFn, {out:{ "inline": 1 }});
```

answered thanks to this question:
[MongoDB count number of new documents per minute based on _id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061114/mongodb-count-number-of-new-documents-per-minute-based-on-id)